# multi level login, and restricted area on code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

i have problem to proces multi level log in and restristed area
there will be 2 type of user: admin and user (common), when a user register they fill form : username, email, and city. --> acces will be set as NULL. for admin acces will be st to 1 (manually)

1. table users:
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `acces' varchar(5),
   'city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
2. table event :
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `event` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   'city`varchar(25) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

the problems are:
1. when a user want to log in, they fill 2 form : email and password. 
2. how to to check if they user or admin
3. if they log in as user, they will be directed to their 'city'. the 'city' will be same to the city when they register.

i really appreciate all possible solution to my problems..
thanks all

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a third table with 'roles', that assigns a user with a role.

instead of checking for the user login, You can limit functions/controllers to rules.

```
if(user_has_role('admin'))
```

You can with some minor effort expand this to multiple roles per user, with each role having it's own permissions etc., there are also several premade libraries for this sort of functionality.

Just google around for user libraries.